# DataGrid row datatrigger/template

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have  the following `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Coll.View}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTransaction}"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedCategory.CategoryName}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payee" Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedPayee.PayeeName}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Withdrawal"  Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deposit"  Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding AccountBalance}" Width="100" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Transactions is an `ObservableCollection` of `TransactionViewModel` items.

The items have this property which is an enum that can be either : Deposit, Withdrawal.

```
private TransactionTypes tType;
public TransactionTypes TransactionType
{
    get { return tType; }
    set
    {
        tType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TransactionType");
    }
}
```

and this one :

```
public double? TransactionAmmount
{
    get { return ammount; }
    set
    {
        ammount = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TransactionAmmount");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind the TransactionAmmount based on the value of TransactionType? If TransactionType is Deposit then bind the TransactionAmmount to the Deposit datagrid column.

If TransactionType is Withdrawal then bind the the TransactionAmmount to the Withdrawal column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the ElementStyle and EdittingElementStyle to achieve what you want in combination with triggers :

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="OK" Binding="{Binding Goedgekeurd,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource GoedkeuringCheckBoxStyle}"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource GoedkeuringCheckBoxStyle}"/>
```

The styles are defined upfront in the resources :

```
<Style x:Key="GoedkeuringCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWachtOpGoedkeuringKlant}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The examples here are taken from my code I did not change them to fit your question exactly but I hope you can follow what is happening and adjust it to your needs.
The point is that the binding is always on row level.

But if you use MVVM then you can do the logic in the viewmodel and not in the view. That could make things more simple.

Comment: In the end made the logic in the viewmodel, but I'll give your code a try, might useful.

Comment: I am using both strategies. Sometimes the viewmodel approach is more convenient. But sometimes it is just a pure styling issue and then I like to put it in the xaml of the view. Good luck.